# Lost Robot program

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

This is an ICPC online round question. I checked sample input and my own imaginary inputs.
[This is link to question](https://www.codechef.com/ACMIND16/problems/ICPC16A)

Here is my code. This code is in Python.

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
  x1,y1,x2,y2=map(int,input().split())
  if (x2-x1==y2-y1)or((x2-x1!=0)and(y2-y1!=0)):
    print('sad')
  elif (x2-x1==0 and y2-y1>0):
    print('up')
  elif (x2-x1==0 and y2-y1<0):
    print('down')
  elif (y2 - y1 == 0 and x2 - x1 > 0):
    print('right')
  elif (y2 - y1 == 0 and x2 - x1 < 0):
    print('left')
```

Can anyone suggest inputs for that code will not work?? If code is correct for all inputs , any modification will be welcomed?.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  Specifically, your question must contain the problem description and the difficulty you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already does not parse the input correctly. Have a look:

```
python /tmp/test.py 
1
0 0 0 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, input().split())
  File "<string>", line 1
    0 0 0 1
      ^
```

Besides from that, it seems to be logical correct.

However, your coding style is improvable. Have a look at my version:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
  x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, input().split())
  if x1 != x2 and y1 != y2:
      print('sad')
  elif x1 == x2 and y1 < y2:
      print('up')
  elif x1 == x2 and y1 > y2:
      print('down')
  elif y1 == y2 and x1 < x2:
      print('right')
  elif y1 == y2 and x1 > x2:
      print('left')
```

The only thing I changed was to improve the conditions. Furthermore, I removed the redundant condition at the bottom.

As a former participant of NWERC and ACM-ICPC I can only suggest to have an eye on readable code. It is not as important as in production code bases, but it helps a lot when you have to debug printed code, as happens at real competitions.

Comment: Actually code is correct, it takes input correctly . I forgot to check indentation while posting this question. Thanks for this readable piece of code. I will improve my coding style. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: This is output of my code:                                                                                    **neo@matrix:~/Documents/mypython$ python3 quiz1.py 
1
0 0 0 1
up
** .

Comment: I accidentally used Python 2.7. With Python 3 it works, you are right.